# Need clarification on assigning values to a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to equate some fault values to some labels using the program below. But i am not getting some datatype errors when i execute the program.
i am even trying to typecast to float. But in spite of that, i am getting some error.

```
 calibs = ['apple_C','ball_C','catalyst_C']
 values = ['0.0','0.0','50.0']
 operators = ['>=','==','<=']     

 def FaultValuesForCalibs(calibs,values,operators):
     faultvalues = []
     print(values)
     for i in range(len(calibs)):
         if (values[i].isalpha()) != True:
             if operators[i] == '==':
                 faultvalues.append(float(values[i]))
             if (operators[i] == '>' or operators[i] == '>='):
                 faultvalues.append(float(values[i] + 1.0))
             if (operators[i] == '<' or operators[i] == '<='):
                 faultvalues.append(float(values[i] - 1.0))
             if operators[i] == '!=':
                 faultvalues.append(float(values[i] + 1.0))
         else:
             if operators[i] == '==':
                 faultvalues.append(values[i])
             if operators[i] == '!=':
                 faultvalues.append(values[i] + 1.0)

     return faultvalues

Actual o/p when i call the function 
FaultValuesForCalibs(calibs,values,operators):

['0.0','0.0','50.0']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-31-5a746950e252>", line 1, in <module>
    FaultValuesForCalibs(calibs,values,operators)

  File 
"C:/Users/arl3cob/Arul/InhibitMatrixTest/PythonScripts_learning/Getting 
column headers.py", line 29, in FaultValuesForCalibs
    faultvalues.append(float(values[i] + 1.0))

TypeError: must be str, not float

Expected O/P:
faultvalues = ['1.0','0.0','49.0']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error, you must enclose every instance of `values[i]` in its own `float()` function, like so: `float(values[i])`. Secondly, you are printing the values given as input, not the output. Do something like `print(FaultValuesForCalibs(<...>))`.
Also, I renamed the lists, so that they are not ambiguous with the parameters given to the function.

```py
_calibs = ['apple_C','ball_C','catalyst_C']
_values = ['0.0','0.0','50.0']
_operators = ['>=','==','<=']     

def FaultValuesForCalibs(calibs,values,operators):
    faultvalues = []
    #print(values)
    for i in range(len(calibs)):
        if (values[i].isalpha()) != True:
            if operators[i] == '==':
                faultvalues.append(float(float(values[i])))
            if (operators[i] == '>' or operators[i] == '>='):
                faultvalues.append(float(float(values[i]) + 1.0))
            if (operators[i] == '<' or operators[i] == '<='):
                faultvalues.append(float(float(values[i]) - 1.0))
            if operators[i] == '!=':
                faultvalues.append(float(float(values[i]) + 1.0))
        else:
            if operators[i] == '==':
                faultvalues.append(float(values[i]))
            if operators[i] == '!=':
                faultvalues.append(float(values[i]) + 1.0)
    return faultvalues
print(FaultValuesForCalibs(_calibs, _values, _operators))
```

You should see the following output:

```
[1.0, 0.0, 49.0]
```